# If Any continuous map from $A$ into $\mathbf{R}$ may be extended to a continuous map of all of $X$ into $\mathbf{R}$. Then $A$ is closed subset.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, separation-axioms

TRUE/ FALSE:  Let $X$ be a normal space and $A$ be a subspace of $X$. If Any continuous map from $A$ into $\mathbf{R}$ may be extended to a continuous map of all of $X$ into $\mathbf{R}$. Then $A$ is closed subset.

My Attempt: I think if $X = \mathbf{R}^n$ or any norm linear space, then it is true. But what about arbitrary metric space or topological space.

Comment: I guess this is true, because constructing a counter-example would be very difficult!

Comment: For a metric space, the answer is affirmative. If $p$ were a point in the closure of $A$ but not in $A$, then $x\mapsto 1/d(p,x)$ (where $d$ is the metric) is continuous on $A$ but cannot be extended continuously to be defined at $p$. For non-metric normal (even compact Hausdorff) spaces, the answer can be negative, as explained in Ulli's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Recall that a subset $A$ of the topological space $X$ is called *C-embedded (in $X$)*, if every continuous function $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can be continuously extended to $X$.

So, you are asking, if every C-embedded subset of a (normal) space is closed.

This is true, if $X$ is completely regular, and every singleton of $X$ is $G_\delta$ (no normality needed here). In particular, this is true in any metric space.
See proposition 2 in the [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266305209_On_the_converse_of_Tietze-Urysohn%27s_extension_theorem) by M. I. Garrido and J. A. Jaramillo, On the Converse Of Tietze-Urysohn’s Extension Theorem (which might also provide further information about your question, in fact, they directly address this question).

However, in general this is not true for normal spaces:

Consider $\beta \mathbb{N}$, the Stone-Cech compactification of the integers, which is compact, hence normal.
Let $x$ be a point of the remainder $\beta \mathbb{N} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ and $A := \beta \mathbb{N} \setminus \{x\}$. Then the Stone-Cech compactifaction of $A$ is $\beta \mathbb{N}$, hence $A$ is almost compact (i.e. $|\beta A \setminus A| \le 1$). Hence $A$ is C-embedded in any completely regular space, which it is a subspace of. In particular it is C-embedded in $\beta \mathbb{N}$ (see [Gillman, Jerison, Rings of continuous functions, 6J](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.b4407145&view=1up&seq=109&q1=6f)). Of course, $A$ is not closed in $\beta \mathbb{N}$.